# read each word and the two words coming after and check some conditions in java

Tags: java, exception

I need to read a file and check if each word is followed by certain "two words" for example, Mr. John Smith. So, While I am reading the file and I face the word Mr. I should check the two words after Mr. to see if they are "John Smith" and count how many times that happens. I wrote the following program

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream  ("TestF.txt"));
String line=reader.readLine();
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    while(line!=null)
    {
        String[] tokens= line.split(" ");
        for (int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++)
        {
                 if tokens[i].equals("Mr.")
                         {              

            if(!(tokens[i+1].isEmpty()))
            {
                if (tokens[i+1].equlas("John")
                                       String s= "John";
                                     else 
                                        s= "Other Name";
            }
            else
                        s="";
        if(!(tokens[i+2].isEmpty()))
            {
                 if (tokens[i+1].equlas("Smith")
                              String s2= "Smith";
                          else 
                              s2= "Other Name";                 
            }
            else
                      s2="";
            if (s.equals("John")&&s2.equals("Smith"))
            {
           if (wordCount.containsKey(tokens[i]))
                wordCount.put(tokens[i], wordCount.get(tokens[i]).intValue()+1);
        else
              wordCount.put(tokens[i], 1);
            }


                       }
        // Go to the next line
        line=reader.readLine();
    }
```

There is a problem with the following line

```
if(!(tokens[i+1].isEmpty()))
```

and the `if(!(tokens[i+2].isEmpty()))` Actually it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26
```

Does that happen because of the last word in the file where there are no two words after? If my guess is right , how can I correct that so I can stop in the last word of the file. If my guess is wrong let me know the reason.
Note: This is just example to show my problem

Comment: Generally, prefer the form: `"John".equals(string)` against `string.equals("John")` -- will save you some trouble and is Null-safe.

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that happen because of the last word in the file where there are no two words after.

Yes, that is correct.

> If my guess is right , how can I correct that so I can stop in the last word of the file.

Just check if you are past the length of the array first:

```
if ((i + 1) < tokens.length && !(tokens[i+1].isEmpty()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that probably is the problem. Just set your loop to stop at `tokens.length-2` like so:

```
for(i=0; i < tokens.length - 2; i++) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always check if the token is null before processing it, it's a good practice to make sure all variable/data structure is valid before you perform any process on it.